# TestNG + Gradle в проекте IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, юнит-тесты, gradle, testng

Пытаюсь  подключить `TestNG` через `Gradle`

вот так выглядит `build.gradle`:

```
group 'MyLib'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'


//Main application class
mainClassName="com.common.Main"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    embeddedJetty
}


dependencies {
    testCompile  group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.0'
    //...
}

test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

делаю `gradle build` проект собирается, но когда в папке **src/test/java**

пытаюсь создать метод с аннотацией `@Test` - эту аннотацию не находит, пакета `org.testng` - нету.

Вопрос: как правильно подключить `TestNG` через `Gradle` в  `IDEA`

Answer (score 1):

testCompile означает что твоя зависимость будет подключена только при тестировании. Попробуй просто compile.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо testCompile напишите implementation и все заработает

Answer (score 0):

на всякий случай, по ссылке описан build.gradle, который работает:

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/using-testng-with-gradle

- делайте Refresh all gradle projects чтобы зависимости перегрузились